# Are chiralgrams real people holograms or just local data simulations?

Tags: death-stranding

> Listen up, Sam. The terminals Amelie’s people built in the towns and cities they passed through on their journey west are called KNOTs. The infrastructure’s there, but the chiral network is offline. Right now, it’s only capable of transmitting voice communications sometimes wired, sometimes wireless, and a small amount of data. So, unless the necessary data’s stored on site, our chiralgrams won’t show up. Amelie and the other Bridges members you’ve seen around the place are “grams” generated with local data, in case you didn’t know. Anyway, all you’ve got to do is find the KNOT, connect your Q-pid, and bring chiral communications online. Once you connect it to the terminal, you’ll be able to initiate “zero time massive data transmission” with the UCA network. And just like that, you’ll reconnect us not only to each other, but to our past. All the lost and fragmented junk data will be compiled and restored. Like bringing a dinosaur back to life from a fossil… 4.6 billion years of history on Earth, all the wisdom and knowledge we lost since the Death Stranding will be ours again. And that, my friend, is how we’ll beat this thing. Once you establish chiral communications, generating “grams” won’t be an issue. You’ll also be able to use chiral printers. Won’t be long before we’re able to send all kinds of things through the wire.

They are only capable transmitting voice communications sometimes wired sometimes wireless. Is it real people who is communicating or not?

Are the chiralgrams real people holograms or just local data simulations?

Comment: At the moment computing power becomes significant enough to contain and model the sum total of all information, then your question becomes moot as the two become indistinguishable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chiralgrams are holograms of real people. When the chiral network is connected, the massive bandwidth available allows for one-to-one remote projections. In this case the chiralgram is like a super high-definition 3D video of the person communicating.

However, when the chiral network isn't available, the very limited bandwidth available only supports voice and a little extra data. If your location already has the data required to create a model of the person communicating, it can do that - it's not faithfully reproducing them one-to-one as they are in reality, but it knows what they look like, so it can show you a model of them. Presumably, the limited data bandwidth could be used to send some animation information so it can roughly reproduce their physical actions as well. In this case the chiralgram is like an animated 3d model or avatar of the person communicating - you're still talking to a real person, it's just the visual aspect that's being simulated.

The chiralgrams are always real people communicating, the only thing that varies is the fidelity of the representation. If you've got full bandwidth, you get full video. If you've got limited bandwidth but the necessary local data, you get a simulated video instead. If you don't have the local data, you only get voice. The full bandwidth chiralgrams are important because they allow absolutely anyone to have real-time face-to-face communication with each other from anywhere within the network, as if they were in the same room together; a big deal for a species which has become very physically separated because of the Stranding.

Comment: Has this society lost almost all techniques of telecommunications?
There are other ways of sending massive amounts of data through a single channel with a big enough alphabet and proper modems and codecs.

Comment: @4.12.22.4.18.0. don't quote me on this, it's a while since I played - the Stranding pretty much knocked out previously existing communications infrastructure and I *think* it's meant to have done something funky with physics that impedes the effectiveness of normal wireless communications. (It's a Kojima game, anyway - you shouldn't expect it to make much sense.)

Comment: Actually, if wireless communications were knocked off, fiber optic and any non wireless communication would still stand. Also visual sight is a type of wireless communications, and some types of wireless communications can be treated as wired communications because at low frequencies the Earth is a conductor. Ok, let's stop trying to make sense of a game that doesn't make sense.

Comment: There's also the timefall to account for.  Any external infrastructure gets destroyed quickly without regular maintenance, and most people have become isolated hermits, unwilling to risk the timefall and BTs. Even the big "cities" are primarily underground and self-contained.  Enough of our broadband system is dependent on above ground infrastructure at the time of the first modern Death Stranding, including but not limited to power stations and server buildings, that it was probably all effectively eliminated in short order.